# How do I get the amount of identical characters in two strings?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to create a function to return the number of identical characters in 2 strings you provide.

```
  let [string1, string2] = target.split(",").map(p => p.trim());
  let [length, char1, char2] = "";
  let total = "0";
  if (!string1 || !string2) return this.errorReply(`Please provide two words or sentences separated by a comma.`);
  if (string1.length > string2.length) {
    length = string1.length;
  } else {
    length = string2.length;
  }
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    char1 = string1.charAt(i);
    char2 = string2.charAt(i);
    if (char1 === char2) total++;
  }
  return this.sendReply(`|html|These two strings have <b>${total}</b> characters in common.`);
```

This is what I had so far, but this checks to see if the first character equals the first, second character equals the second, etc.
I need it to basically take the 1st character of the 1st string, and check to see if it's the same as ANY of the characters in the 2nd string, and once it's checked all of them, it moves onto the 2nd character of the 1st string and repeats. Any help on how I would do this?

Comment: if the first string has an `a` and the second string has 5 `a`, does that count as 1 or 5?

Comment: 1, just how many times two alike characters occur between the two strings. If there's 3 `a` in the first and second string it should count as 3.

Comment: If you unaccept my answer, I'll delete it. My answer doesn't address the case of repeated characters. I came up with a solution but is similar to Anthony's.

Comment: @ZacharyHartin - Select anthony's answer. That is the correct one. I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Anthony's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404474/2924577).

**Following answer doesn't take into consideration repeated characters and hence gives wrong output if there are any repeated characters.**

---

Iterate on first string using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to check if current character is present in second string.

```js
function getIdenticalCount(str1, str2) {
  let count = 0;
  
  for (let ch of str1) {
    if (str2.includes(ch)) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  
  return count;
}

console.log(getIdenticalCount("apple", "bat"));
console.log(getIdenticalCount("cat", "dog"));
console.log(getIdenticalCount("apple", "pineapple"));
```

Comment: this produces an incorrect value of `4` for `getIdenticalCount('aabc','abc')` per OP requirements

Comment: Yes, that's right  @Anthony. Just noticed that. Working on fixing that. Came up with a similar solution as yours using map.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const getStringMap = str => {
  const map = new Map();
  
  for(let char of str) {
    if(map.has(char)) {
      map.set(char, map.get(char) + 1);
    } else {
      map.set(char, 1);
    }
  }
  
  return map;
};

const getCommonCount = (str1, str2) => {
  const map1 = getStringMap(str1);
  const map2 = getStringMap(str2);
  
  let commonCount = 0;
  
  for(let k of map1.keys()) {
    if(map2.has(k)) {
      commonCount += Math.min(map1.get(k), map2.get(k));
    }
  }
  
  return commonCount;
};

console.log(getCommonCount('aabcc','aabc'));
```

This will handle multiple letters in both strings per the requirement that if both have *x* of a letter, that is *x* letters in common but if one string has 1 of a letter and another has >1, it is only 1 in common.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily. First convert one of the strings to an array and then just use `Array.filter` along with `Array.includes` to determine if there is a common char.

You can then return it how you want. The below example will return an array of unique matches.

**Get Unique Chars**

```js
const getCommonChars = (str1, str2) => {
  const letters = str1.split('');
  return [...new Set(letters.filter(s => str2.includes(s)))];
};

const result1 = getCommonChars('abcdefg', 'this is a sentence');
console.log('result1', result1)

const result2 = getCommonChars('aaaaaabbbbbbxxxxx', 'a blue bird can be exxxxxtra small');
console.log('result2', result2)
```

**Get Counts**

```js
const getCommonCharsWithCounts = (str1, str2) => {
  const letters = str1.split('');
  const lettersToSearch = str2.split('');
  return letters.reduce( (acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = lettersToSearch.filter(l => l === curr).length;
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

const result3 = getCommonCharsWithCounts('abcdefg', 'this is a sentence');
console.log('result3', result3)

const result4 = getCommonCharsWithCounts('aaaaaabbbbbbxxxxx', 'a blue bird can be exxxxxtra small');
console.log('result4', result4)
```