# Sorting strings by number of identical characters

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

There is a file where there are many lines with a random set of letters.
Scanning each line, you need to find the number of lines that contain exactly two letters of any letter, and then separately count the lines that contain exactly three letters of any letter. You need to get the result of multiplying the rows from the first case by the number of rows in the second.

How can I optimize this code or make it better??

Strings in file example (we need sort it all and file can has infiniy amout of strings) : "prtkqyluibmtcwqaezjmhgfndx
prtkqylusbsmcwvaezjmhgfndt
prgkqyluibsocwvamzjmhgkndx
prjkqyluibsocwvahzjmhgfnsx
prtkqylcibsocwvzezjohgfndx
prtkqyluiksocwziezjmhgfndx
prikqyluiksocwvaezjmkgfndx
prtkgyluibsocwvwezjehgfndx
prtkqyluiysocwvaezjghxfndx
prtkqwluibsoxwvaezjmhgfhdx
prtkqylgibsocwvabzjmhzfndx
prtknyltibnocwvaezjmhgfndx
prdkqyluibrocwvaezjmhgnndx
prtwqyluibsoctvcezjmhgfndx
mrtkqyluibgocwvakzjmhgfndx"

My code:

```
function solution(arrOfStrings) {
  let sumOfTwo = 0;
  let sumOfThree = 0;

  for (const string of arrOfStrings) {
    const chars = {};
    for (const char of string) {
      chars[char] = (chars[char] || 0) + 1;
    }
    console.log(chars);
    if (
      Object.entries(chars)
        .filter((char) => char[1] == 2)
        .map((char) => char[0]).length > 0
    ) {
      sumOfTwo += 1;
    }
    if (
      Object.entries(chars)
        .filter((char) => char[1] == 3)
        .map((char) => char[0]).length > 0
    ) {
      sumOfThree += 1;
    }
  }

  return sumOfTwo * sumOfThree;
}

let fs = require("fs");
const text = fs.readFileSync("./someTextFile.txt").toString("utf-8");
const arr = text.split("\n");

solution(arr);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the amount of identical characters in two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404294/how-do-i-get-the-amount-of-identical-characters-in-two-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of possible optimizations:

```
function solution(arrOfStrings) {
  const out = arrOfStrings.reduce((o, s) =>
    (o[s.length]++ || (o[s.length] = 1), o), {});
  return (out[2] ?? 0) * (out[3] ?? 0);
}

let fs = require("fs");
const text = fs.readFileSync("./someTextFile.txt").toString("utf-8");
const arr = text.split("\n");

solution(arr);
```